# C# JSON serialize/deserialize property name shortening

Tags: serialization, deserialization

I serialize with Newtonsoft and store the data in Redis. I want to shorten the property names to reduce the size of the data, because my property names are too long and there is too much data.

Example:

```
{
 User:{
  UserFullNameBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla: "blabla"
 }
}
```

but I want it to be like this; short property names.

```
{
 User:{
  SHRTNM1: "blabla"
 }
}
```

I don't use  `[JsonProperty("name")]` because there are too many classes and they're not mine. Anybody have the idea how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_IContractResolver.htm is what are you looking for.

It allows you to customize almost every aspect of how a .NET object gets serialized to JSON, including changing serialization behavior at runtime.